# Fingerprint authentication in React Native App

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I know this is a common problem to ask but I've been wondering if it is possible to make a fingerprint registration to my app, most of the resources from the internet says that react can't do that for some security reason,
My question is for clarification, it is possible to do fingerprint registration through my app and save it either to the local or to the OS? but I've seen many apps register their fingerprint through their app, it is possible to `react-native`? What should I do? It would be great if anybody give me a guide and clarification for this, thank you so much in advance!.

Comment: Did you try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fingerprint-scanner

Comment: @Thanhal Not yet but I just want to clarify if it is possible to register fingerprint from my app?. The link I think that you provided is the registration of fingerprint is made from the OS not in the mobile app instead, I guess

Comment: You can't register fingerprints in your app. You can use a react wrapper around native libraries, such as the local authentication framework on iOS, to prompt the user to present their finger and get back a yes/no answer as to whether it matched an enrolled finger